# Is there a conditional formatting formula for highlighting cells with values that are within a specific range to values in other cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

[image: Excel Image]

In the image attached, there is a list of frequencies.  Essentially, I'm trying to ensure that the frequencies listed maintain a separation of at least 0.3.  With the correct formula, conditional formatting should be able to highlight cells A1 and A2 since they're within 0.3 of each other.

To provide some background, the A column is a list of backup frequencies and column B is a list of primary frequencies. Only primary frequencies that require a backup frequency has something in their respective B column.

Comment: Could you update the excel sheet, there will be two tabs one for current data and another for your expected result. It will be helpful to solve the issues.

Comment: I don't see how that picture supports your explanation and why B13 and A1 should be highlighted (or even where they are on this picture).

Comment: Sorry, edited the question to reflect the right column/row references.

Comment: It is not much better. Is the top left cell A1? Didn't you swap the columns, as you are saying on some B cells are filled whereas they all are? Is the 0.3 difference applied to only one column? Across columns? Between A1 and B1? Between A1 and any of B?

Comment: Yes, so 303.625 is A1 and 237.125 is B1. I didn’t understand your second question, but I didn’t swap the image. A column are secondary frequencies, which is why all of them aren’t filled in (because I don’t need a secondary for every primary frequency). B column is the list of primary frequencies. 0.3 difference is applied across all columns and rows, both A and B.

Comment: So "in their respective B column" is "in their respective A column". Given that the differences are searched across everything, does that mean you want different colors for different pairs of numbers that are within 0.3 of each other? So if A1 and A2 are within 0.3 you paint them red and then (say) B14 and B19 are also within 0.3 of each other (but not A1 or A2), so you paint them a different shade of red? What if A2 is withing 0.3 in positive direction from A1, and withing 0.3 in negative direction from A3, but A1 and A3 are not withing 0.3 from each other, do you paint A2 in *two* colors?

Comment: A different shade would be nice, but not needed.  Just like in your first example, I'd just like one color, providing the user with a visual by highlighting all the frequency conflicts within 0.3 of each other.  The whole A1, A2, and A3 wouldn't matter to me.  So long as I see three highlighted cells, I can immediately correlate that there is an error and make the necessary changes.

Comment: I just figured it out using what rangraj r provided.  I used this: =COUNTIFS($A$1:$B$15,"<="&A1+0.3,$A$1:$B$15,">="&A1-0.3)>1.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using conditional formatting with formulas

Select Cells A1 to A15

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wrz5.jpg)

Goto Conditional formatting -> new rules -> Use formula

and enter the formula below

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$15,"<="&A1+0.3,$A$1:$A$15,">="&A1-0.3)>1
```

Format with green fill , click ok and apply

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihXAu.png)

Voila.

You can use the same for column B if you want, just change the reference